# replace/fill columns base on agg of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF as follows:

```
|   feat1 | feat2   | feat3    | feat4   | label |
|--------:|---------|----------|---------|-------|
|  0.1856 | -0.186  | 1.681    | 0.56781 |   0   |
| 0.78671 | 0.1761  | -0.671   | 0.176   |   0   |
|  -1.681 | 0.15689 | -0.18689 | 0.681   |   0   |
```

I want to replace the `label` column where the mean of all `feat` features is > 0. I tried this:

```py
feat = [f for f in df.columns if "feat" in f]
df.loc[df[feat].mean() > 0, "label"] = 1
```

But it does not seem to work right.

Comment: `df[feat].mean(axis=1)` add axis=1, to calculate by row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter all columns containing `feat` and calculate `mean` across `axis=1` , and convert to int after comparison.

```
df['label'] = df.filter(like='feat').mean(1).gt(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

---

```
     feat1    feat2    feat3    feat4  label
0  0.18560 -0.18600  1.68100  0.56781      1
1  0.78671  0.17610 -0.67100  0.17600      1
2 -1.68100  0.15689 -0.18689  0.68100      0
```